# In Scala, how to use 'toArray()' to turn a stack to a array？

Tags: scala, stack, toarray

I use the 'toArray' api of immutable.Stack like the codes below  in Scala, but it reports error.

```
var stack1 = mutable.Stack[Long]()
val array = stack1.toArray();
```

It reports 'Cannot resolve reference toArray with such signature' about toArray
 and "unspecified value parameters" about the '()' of toArray() !

[An image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9iuTN.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### TLDR

the correct way is to call `toArray` without parentheses

#### Explanation

`toArray` function has the following signature (you can use <kbd>tab</kbd> to expand signatures in Scala repl):

```
scala> stack1.toArray
   def toArray[B >: Long](implicit evidence$1: scala.reflect.ClassTag[B]): Array[B]
```

It expects `ClassTag` implicit parameter:

```
scala> stack1.toArray
res2: Array[Long] = Array()

scala> stack1.toArray(scala.reflect.classTag[Long])
res3: Array[Long] = Array()
```

In the first case, parameter is substituted by compiler. In the second case parameter passed explicitly.

Comment: What does TLDR mean？

Comment: it's an abbreviation for Too Long Didn't Read - basically is a very short explanation of a long wall of text that usually follows :)